# Android Studio: Passing RadioButtons using Intent ERROR NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, radio-button, radio-group

I am a beginner so i apologize in advance
I get the following Error when running this program:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
```

here is my code for "Quiz"

```
public class Quiz extends Activity {
Button btn;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
RadioButton rb4;
```

then below that: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qXiY.png)

And the xml for "quiz":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/rg">
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 1"
    android:id="@+id/rb1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rb2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 2"
    android:id="@+id/rb2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rb3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rb1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rb1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:checked="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 3"
    android:id="@+id/rb3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rb4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rb2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rb2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:checked="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Option 4"
    android:id="@+id/rb4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rb3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rb3"
    android:checked="false" />
</RadioGroup>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Question:"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Second activity (Quiz1): [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aS75.png)

any help is appreciated thank you lots <3

Comment: Would help if you just posted all of the relevant code into the question instead of images. Makes it more difficult for people trying to understand your code and help your problem.

Comment: You're right! thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadioGroup rg need a init step to check a RadioButton before invoke getCheckedRadioButtonId().

Like this:

```
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1;
rg = ....
rb1 = ....
// check a RadioButton first
rg.check(R.id.rb1);
```

And make sure that your id in "findViewByid" method is similar to RadioGroup's id in Layout Xml.

Comment: Still get the error:  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doesntmatter.choosecharacter/com.doesntmatter.choosecharacter.Quiz}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.check(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Could you show me that xml file which the Quiz Activity used?

Comment: the Error message means you have not created the RadioGroup instance, so : ( . It may happens when the RadioGroup is missing in your Layout xml or use a wrong id.

Comment: I added the XML for quiz (so the first activity) on the original post above

Comment: Look at the xml and the RadioGroup's id is rg, but in your code "findViewByID(R.id.rg1)" @JessicaAdams

Comment: Perfect it worked! Thanks to both of you, the rg.check was working perfectly I just messed up the ID as Fergus mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you don't init your RadioGroup button **radioGroup** in your `Quiz1` class.

Comment: Still get the error:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference`